# Delay in IE edge browser while browsing a geotiff(.tiff extension) image

Tags: microsoft-edge, geotiff

Tried browsing an .tiff extension image (size > 500mb) in Microsoft edge and it is taking few seconds to get selected depends upon the size of the image.

But for other extensions, there is no delay. This occurs only in Microsoft edge.

Could anyone please help me whether this is a limitation with Microsoft edge or whats happening in the background?

```
<form>
  <label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
  <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" />
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

*Note: to reproduce this, try uploading by changing the extension to .tiff of any large image which u have*

Comment: Do you mean after clicking the file control Browse button, it will have delay to display the  Choose file window? If that is the case, I have checked it on my side, it seems that everything works well, both IE, Edge and Chrome will have a little delay to show the window, it is almost 1~2 seconds. Perhaps the issue is related to the IE, Edge performance, try to clear the browser data and recheck it.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT thanks for your reply.. The delay is not to display the choose file window. The delay is after selecting a file from the choose file window, to display the chosen file in the text box. Everything works fine for small size files. But for file with size > 500 MB or 1 GB there is delay. Tried clearing cache also. but for larger files, delay is still there

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on my side, it only spends almost 1~2 seconds in IE and Edge browser. Can you tell us your computer OS version and configuration information, and which version of IE and Edge browser are you using? Besides, please check your code whether there has some javascript event which will handle the selected file. And you could also try to reset IE and Edge browser setting, then check if it solved the problem.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT did u selected a large size file?

Comment: Yes, the file size is 2.14 G, the screenshot [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSdZh.gif).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT not in IE 11. The issue is in Edge. Please give a try in Microsoft Edge browser

Comment: The result in Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMSaC.gif), if you are using the Edge Chromium (Version 81.0.416.64 (Official build) (64-bit)), you could check [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYMsF.gif).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT my edge version is 44.17763.831.0 and windows 10 OS. Is that issue is because of this version mismatch?

Comment: I have tested the sample in Edge 44.17763.831.0, it still spends only 1~2 seconds, same with the Edge 44.18362.449.0 version. Please check your Edge browser whether it install any extension? try to [reset the Edge browser setting](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-microsoft-edge-browser-to-default-settings-in-windows-10) or [reinstall Edge browser](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/reinstall-microsoft-edge/15374c1e-f5c5-44e7-9378-cd33e48e8395).  If still not working, I suggest you could try to use the other type of image (extensions).